# changing height of time column in timegrid view in fullcalendar react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

[image]

I have a use case when I use the timegrid view for fullcalendar with react, I use time grid view and I want to make the time column on the left expand by the height of the events(like the images) instead of taking fixed height, is there any way to do that? thanks

Comment: No, because then the times in the grid would not be relative to each other in terms of the length of time they represent, which would destroy the purpose of that type of grid. You could always use dayGridWeek view if you are not so bothered about the time display being consistent.

Comment: and is there any option to add this time customly in the  dayGridWeek?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by that, exactly.

Comment: I mean if I used dayGridWeek is there any option for me to customize it and add the column of the times on the left on my own ?

Comment: No. Because then it would be back to a time grid again